# I´m making a simple tic-tac-toe game in C and it ends after the first input

Tags: c, if-statement, tic-tac-toe, control-flow

I have this problem and I don´t know what´s wrong. The code doesn´t have any errors or warnings but it always take the first `if` statement of the checkVictory function as correct.

I've tried comparing my code with another one that actually works and it looks identical to me. I´m pretty sure the mistake is in the checkVictory function because I used a variable called flag to check every if statement of the function and my returnValue (which is used as an indicator of my game status) always get triggered by the first if.

Here´s my code... (sorry for the indentation this is my first time using the website)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void board();
void markBoard(char mark);
int checkVictory();

int player, choice, flag;
char list[10] = {'-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

void main() {
    int gameStatus;
    char mark;
    player = 1;

    do{
        board();

        // change turns
        player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

        //input
        printf("Player %d, enter a number: ", player);
        scanf("%i", &choice);

        // set the correct character based on player turn
        mark = (player == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

        markBoard(mark);
    
        gameStatus = checkVictory();
    
        player++; 
    } while (gameStatus == -1);

    if (gameStatus == 1) {
        printf("Player %d WIN", --player);
        printf("\nflag: %i", flag);
    }
    else{
        printf("Draw");
    }
}

void board() {
    system("cls"); 
    printf("\n\n\t   tic tac toe\n\n");
    printf("Player 1 (X)    -    Player 2 (O)\n\n");

    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c  \n", list[1], list[2], list[3]);
    printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c  \n", list[4], list[5], list[6]);
    printf("_____|_____|_____\n");
    printf("     |     |     \n");
    printf("  %c  |  %c  |  %c  \n", list[7], list[8], list[9]);
    printf("     |     |     \n");

    printf("\n");
}

void markBoard(char mark) {
    if (choice == 1 && list[1] == '1')
        list[1] = mark;
    else if (choice == 2 && list[2] == '2')
        list[2] = mark;
    else if (choice == 3 && list[3] == '3')
        list[3] = mark;
    else if (choice == 4 && list[4] == '4')
        list[4] = mark;
    else if (choice == 5 && list[5] == '5')
        list[5] = mark;
    else if (choice == 6 && list[6] == '6')
        list[6] = mark;
    else if (choice == 7 && list[7] == '7')
        list[7] = mark;
    else if (choice == 8 && list[8] == '8')
        list[8] = mark;
    else if (choice == 9 && list[9] == '9')
        list[9] = mark;
    else {
        printf("Invalid move\n");
        player--;
        getch();
    }
}

/*********************************************FUNCTION TO RETURN GAME STATUS1 FOR GAME IS OVER WITH RESULT-1 FOR GAME IS IN PROGRESSO GAME IS OVER AND NO RESULT**********************************************/

int checkVictory() {
    int returnValue = 0;

    if (list[1] && list[2] == list[2] && list[3]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if (list[4] && list[5] == list[5] && list[6]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 2;
    }
    else if (list[7] && list[8] == list[8] && list[9]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 3;
    }
    else if (list[1] && list[4] == list[4] && list[7]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 4;
    }
    else if (list[2] && list[5] == list[5] && list[8]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 5;
    }
    else if (list[3] && list[6] == list[6] && list[9]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 6;
    }
    else if (list[1] && list[5] == list[5] && list[9]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 7;
    }
    else if (list[3] && list[5] == list[5] && list[7]) {
        returnValue = 1;
        flag = 8;
    }
    else if (list[1] != '1' && list[2] != '2' && list[3] != '3' &&
             list[4] != '4' && list[5] != '5' && list[6] != '6' && 
             list[7] != '7' && list[8] != '8' && list[9] != '9') {
        returnValue = 0;
    }
    else
        returnValue = -1;

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: `if (list[1] && list[2] == list[2] && list[3])` is always true, so `checkVictory` returns 1 ending the game. What are you trying to do with that code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the code below.

```
if (list[1] && list[2] == list[2] && list[3]) {
        returnValue = 1;
```

Your condition:

```
list[1] && list[2] == list[2] && list[3]
```

Parses as:

```
list[1] && (list[2] == list[2]) && list[3]
```

Because no element of `list` is `0`, they all test as true. Likewise, `list[2]` will *always* be equal to itself. Consequently this condition is always true. `checkVictory` will always return `1`. When this is called, and `gameSttatus` is set to `1`, the do-while loop ends.

Comment: OH I totally get it know, I switched the symbols. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If an answer has answered your question, feel free to upvote and accept it as you are able.